# How to Use Medium Trust in Asp.net 

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, configuration

I have an application it works fine locally and when I deploy it remotely it gives error, after contacting the hosting company i was said that to set the Trust level to medium 
After setting the trust level to medium it gives the ****"Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using  from an inherited configuration file." ****

```
  **<trust level="Medium" > is where error comes in web.config**
```

The error only comes in the line trust level which is set to medium and
The configuration error only comes on hosting server not local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They want you to set your local IIS to medium trust to figure out the problem. From IIS manager, select Sites\Default Web Site, then in the center pane, select .NET Trust Levels. Change it from Full(internal) to Medium (web_mediumtrust.config).